# Need to set up for music production and audio recording

Tags: music

I want to record, mix, and master audio (Music, skits) I need to know what are good settings and programs on Ubuntu for this. While I will use it too update and whatnot, I will disconnect from the internet soon, so if you could please let me know. Thank You

Comment: You're asking for opinionated discussion which is not a fit for Ask Ubuntu, which is for asking questions which can be answered directly. For discussion, you should see http://ubuntuforums.org/ perhaps.

Comment: Check out [Ubuntu Studio](http://www.ubuntustudio.org).

Comment: Apart from what @dobey said, I do not think Linux will help much for music production. Seems like you need some professional software, which usually is targeted for OSX or Windows platforms.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs That's not true. There's plenty of software available on Ubuntu. But as I said, this isn't a discussion forum. :)

Answer (score 0):

The top programs for audio are:

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)
[Ardour](http://ardour.org/)
[QTractor](http://qtractor.sourceforge.net/)
[Jokosher](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jokosher.mirror/)

Comment: You forget off an important piece of software: the Linux MultiMedia Studio my friend. (lmms) http://lmms.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo Yes, that is a good one :)